# How can I return a generic type that implements another protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, urlsession

I have networking module that implements a standard interface for exposing my networking client

```swift
protocol HTTPClientTask {
    func cancel()
}
protocol HTTPClient {
    @discardableResult
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask
}
```

This is implemented something like

```swift
final class URLSessionHTTPClient: HTTPClient {
    
    private let session: URLSession
    private struct RequestError: Error { }
    private struct URLSessionTaskWrapper: HTTPClientTask {
        let wrapped: URLSessionTask
        func cancel() {
            wrapped.cancel()
        }
    }
    
    init(session: URLSession = .shared) {
        self.session = session
    }
    
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            completion(Result {
                if let error = error {
                    throw error
                } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    return (response, data)
                } else {
                    throw RequestError()
                }
            })
        }
        task.resume()
        return URLSessionTaskWrapper(wrapped: task)
    }
}
```

An example to run in a playground would be

```swift
let requestURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!

let httpClient = URLSessionHTTPClient()

httpClient.execute(.init(url: requestURL)) { result in
    if let code = try? result.get().response.statusCode {
        print(code)
    }
}
```

I have another framework I'd like to add to my app that exposes an interface that is identical.

I don't want my other module to have a dependancy on this networking module, instead I'd prefer it to expose the interface it requires and have my networking module be dependant on it.

So the following interface is exposed by my other module

```swift
protocol AuthHTTPClientTask {
    func cancel()
}

protocol AuthHTTPClient {
    @discardableResult
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> AuthHTTPClientTask
}
```

As you can see the interfaces are exact, however I was hoping to avoid creating an entire `URLSessionHTTPClient` just for that interface - `URLSessionAuthHTTPClient` or something as the behaviour etc is the same.

Is it possible to create some sort of type that `URLSessionHTTPClient` implements that allows it to return `AuthHTTPClientTask` OR `HTTPClientTask`?

I thought I could do something like

```swift
extension HTTPClientTask: AuthHTTPClientTask { }

final class URLSessionHTTPClient: HTTPClient, AuthHTTPClient {
    
    private let session: URLSession
    private struct RequestError: Error { 
.........
```

But this produces `Extension of protocol 'HTTPClientTask' cannot have an inheritance clause` and `Type 'URLSessionHTTPClient' does not conform to protocol 'AuthHTTPClient'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error about `inheritance clause` as a constraint is required for conformance purposes, in your example the compiler thinks it is an inheritance.

You could create a generic, private method that handles dispatching the request and extend the return types of that method to conform to your module types.

```swift
protocol HTTPClientTask {
    func cancel()
}

protocol HTTPClient {
    @discardableResult
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask
}

protocol AuthHTTPClientTask {
    func cancel()
}

protocol AuthHTTPClient {
    @discardableResult
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> AuthHTTPClientTask
}


private struct URLSessionTaskWrapper {
    let wrapped: URLSessionTask
    func cancel() {
        wrapped.cancel()
    }
}

extension URLSessionTaskWrapper: HTTPClientTask { }
extension URLSessionTaskWrapper: AuthHTTPClientTask { }

final class URLSessionHTTPClient {
    
    private let session: URLSession
    private struct RequestError: Error { }

    init(session: URLSession = .shared) {
        self.session = session
    }
    
    private func dispatch(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTaskWrapper {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            completion(Result {
                if let error = error {
                    throw error
                } else if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    return (response, data)
                } else {
                    throw RequestError()
                }
            })
        }
        task.resume()
        return URLSessionTaskWrapper(wrapped: task)
    }
}


extension URLSessionHTTPClient: HTTPClient {
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> HTTPClientTask {
        return dispatch(request, completion)
    }
}

extension URLSessionHTTPClient: AuthHTTPClient {
    func execute(_ request: URLRequest, _ completion: @escaping (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> Void) -> AuthHTTPClientTask {
        return dispatch(request, completion)
    }
}

let requestURL = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!

let httpClient: HTTPClient = URLSessionHTTPClient()
httpClient.execute(.init(url: requestURL)) { result in
    if let code = try? result.get().response.statusCode {
        print("HTTP", code)
    }
}

let authzHTTPClient: AuthHTTPClient = URLSessionHTTPClient()
authzHTTPClient.execute(.init(url: requestURL)) { result in
    if let code = try? result.get().response.statusCode {
        print("Authz", code)
    }
}
```